# x86_64 ASM: Alternative to movq?

Tags: assembly, mmx

Is there an alternate way to put a qword in an mmx register?

For example, in this code snippet:

```
db random 0xaa,0xaa,0xaa,0xaa,0xaa,0xaa,0xaa,0xaa
run:
    movq mm2, [rel random]
```

I can now work with that as a qword 0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa and do pxor etc with it. Is there some other way I could put that data in the register? Maybe by pushing/popping to it?

Comment: Why? But you could also `movq` it from a GPR

Comment: You could move from an immediate value?

Comment: I just want some way to get that data in the register without using movq

Comment: No idea why you want to do this, but you can avoid `movq` with for example `pxor mm2, mm2; pxor mm2, [rel random]` or similar.

Comment: That's brilliant @Jester ! Thank you :)

Comment: @Jester Is there a way to make it also go the other direction without movq? To solve: movq [rel random], mm2

If so, please post it as a solution and I can mark this as solved :)

Comment: @user2059300 but what's so bad about movq in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why you want to do this, but you can avoid `movq` if you zero the register and then bring in the value using some operation, such as:

```
pxor mm2, mm2
pxor mm2, [rel random]
```

Alternatively, you can load the words using `pinsrw`:

```
pinsrw mm2, [rel random], 0
pinsrw mm2, [rel random + 2], 1
pinsrw mm2, [rel random + 4], 2
pinsrw mm2, [rel random + 6], 3
```

This approach also works in reverse using `pextrw` but have to go through a general purpose register:

```
pextrw eax, mm2, 0
mov [rel random], ax
pextrw eax, mm2, 1
mov [rel random + 2], ax
pextrw eax, mm2, 2
mov [rel random + 4], ax
pextrw eax, mm2, 3
mov [rel random + 6], ax
```

If only `movq` must be avoided but `maskmovq` can be used then you can do:

```
pcmpeqb mm1, mm1
lea rdi, [rel random]
maskmovq mm2, mm1
```

Comment: @user2059300: there are really two separate instructions, both called `movq`.  One is `movq mm, mm/m64` (so it has an `mm,mm` form, and an `mm, [memory]` form.  It's under `MOVQ` in Intel's x86 insn ref).   The other is for moving data between integer and vector registers, and is under `MOVD/MOVQ` in the insn ref.  So you could `mov r64, imm64` / `movq mm, r64`.  This insn also has a `mm, [memory]` form, but only works in 64bit mode.